# SAS Informat giving different results

Tags: sas

I am using below codes for SAS Informats:

1.

```
DATA a; 
INPUT NAME $ AGE SALARY ;
INFORMAT SALARY DOLLAR5.2; 
DATALINES; 
ABC 20 $9878.34223123123123
;
```

2.

```
DATA b; 
INPUT NAME $ AGE SALARY : DOLLAR5.2;
DATALINES; 
ABC 20 $9878.34223123123123
;
```

3.

```
DATA c; 
INPUT NAME $ AGE SALARY DOLLAR5.2;
DATALINES; 
ABC 20 $9878.34223123123123
;
```

The first two codes are storing the salary as "9878.34223123123123" that is actual value without the dollar sign, whereas the last one stores it as 98.78 only.

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: What stored and displayed values are you trying to achieve for your dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is that a decimal specification on an **INFORMAT** has nothing to do with restricting the precision of the number. Instead it is instructions on where to place the decimal point when the source text does not contain one.  If you used DOLLAR5.2 to read the string '12345' the result will be 123.45.

The secondary point you raise is that when using list mode input SAS will ignore the width specified on the informat and instead use the width of the available data.  Your first example is using list mode input and your second is using formatted mode input.  The third example is also using list mode input since you include the colon prefix in front of the  in-line informat specification.

If you want to round the value to two decimal places use the `ROUND()` function after reading the source data.

```
salary = round(salary,.01);
```

Comment: @ Tom: you are just awesome. A quick question, I have sas base certification exam in 2 weeks. What do you suggest I read? I have gone through the SAS's certification book already.